# How can i add '/' in a string in Js but then invert it only if it has not found the slash in the previous step using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

my problem is a bit odd, I was trying to use replace() and Regex to transform a string in the following manner:

- from an input of '203012' (so if there isn't a slash) the output should be '12/2030'
- from an input of '12/2030' (so if there is already a slash) the output should remain the same

I know i could you use conditions to check the string before using replace() but I was trying to achieve using just replace() and RegEx.

What I tried was using the likes of

```js
const result = input.replace(
  /\//g, replaced => replaced.replace(
    /^(.{4})(.{2})/, '$2/$1'
  )
)
```

Of course this code replaces the eventual slash before but it always inverts inverts the values when re-inserting the '/'.

Does anybody knows how to achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Just use `input.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})$/, '$2/$1')`. Why replace multiple occurrences of `/`?

Comment: This answers the question, I just didn't think of that since I'm still learning regexes, my understanding is it just matches the first 4 digits chars and the subsequent 2, then does a replace with <match_2>/<match_1>, while if it already contains a '/' the regex doesn't match at all, solving the problem. Thank you, it is a good solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
input = input.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})$/, '$2/$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TiJ6ad/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{4})` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): four digits
- `(\d{2})` - Capturing group 2 (`$2`): two digits
- `$` - end of string.

If the string consists of merely six digits, there will be a match and a `/` will be inserted between the Group 2 and Group 1 values.

If there is a slash, there will be no match, and thus, no slash will be added.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const strings = ['203012', '12/2030'];
strings.forEach(x => console.log(x, '=>', x.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})$/, '$2/$1')))
```